# How to Append/Updated records in SQL Server Virtual Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to Append/Updated records in Virtual table.

```
 TableA(ID,IdentifyingNumber,Included) TableB(ID,IdentifyingNumber,Included)

   Records in TableA 
             1, 101, 0
             2, 102, 1
             3, 103, 1

   Records in TableB 
             1, 201, 0
             2, 202, 0
```

I need out put of Both table records in TableC

```
TableC(IdentifyingNumberA,IncludedA,IdentifyingNumberB,IncludedB)
    Records in TableC
               101, 0,  201, 0
               102, 1,  202, 0
               103, 1,  Null, Null
```

This is my first table

```
INSERT INTO @EntityListL(RowID,EntityID,IdentifyingNumberL,IncludedL)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.EntityID DESC) AS Row, 
           d.EntityID,d.IdentifyingNumber,d.Included FROM @EntityList d 
    where d.Included = 0
    ORDER BY d.IdentifyingNumber
```

This is my second table

```
    INSERT INTO @EntityListR(RowID,EntityID,IdentifyingNumberR,IncludedR)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.EntityID DESC) AS Row, 
           d.EntityID,d.IdentifyingNumber,d.Included FROM @EntityList d 
    where d.Included = 1
    ORDER BY d.IdentifyingNumber
```

I try to get out put with below SQL statement

```
select A.IdentifyingNumber as IdentifyingNumberL, A.Included as IncludedL,
       B.IdentifyingNumber as IdentifyingNumberR, B.Included as IncludedR from
(
    select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdentifyingNumber) AS Row,
            IdentifyingNumber, Included
    from @EntityList  where Included=0
) 
A
left outer join 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdentifyingNumber) AS Row,
           IdentifyingNumber,Included from @EntityList  where Included=1
)B
 on A.Row=B.Row
```

Please let me know how can i achieve in SQL Server.

Thanks in an advance

Comment: by virtual do you mean temp table? have you actually attempted anything or are you just hoping someone will give you an answer?

Comment: Yes in virtual table and i try to lot but not exect out put.

Comment: add what you have tried to the question, then anyone that answers can use that as a basis and correct what is wrong.

Comment: I updated my question, what i done, but in this case i can not get all records which is store in TableA and TableB so left outer join its not proper way

Comment: Just a note.  An in memory table works the same as any standard SQL table with respect to Joins Selects Inserts Updates and deletes.

Comment: Please ensure that your question reflects the data that you are working with. If you have 7 records in table A and 5 in table B, your question should show those records, whereas it is currently 3 in table A, and 2 in table B.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this SQL....

```
select A.IdentifyingNumber as IdentifyingNumberL, A.Included as IncludedL,
       B.IdentifyingNumber as IdentifyingNumberR, B.Included as IncludedR from
(
    select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdentifyingNumber) AS Row,
            IdentifyingNumber, Included
    from @EntityList  where Included=0
) 
A
full outer join 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdentifyingNumber) AS Row,
           IdentifyingNumber,Included from @EntityList  where Included=1
)B
 on A.Row=B.Row
```

That SQL give all types of records in Table.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
select a.IdentifyingNumber, a.Included, b.IdentifyingNumber, b.Included
from #A a
left outer join #B b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Here's a full test:

```
create table #A (ID int, IdentifyingNumber int ,Included int)
create table #B (ID int, IdentifyingNumber int ,Included int)

insert into #A values (1, 101, 0)
insert into #A values (2, 102, 1)
insert into #A values (3, 103, 1)

insert into #B values (1, 201, 0)
insert into #B values (2, 202, 0)

select a.IdentifyingNumber, a.Included, b.IdentifyingNumber, b.Included
 from #A a left outer join #B b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Results in:

```
IdentifyingNumber Included    IdentifyingNumber Included
----------------- ----------- ----------------- -----------
101               0           201               0
102               1           202               0
103               1           NULL              NULL
```

To put it into a new temp table you'll need to differentiate between your column names:

```
SELECT a.IdentifyingNumber AS IdentifyingNumberA
    ,a.Included AS IncludedA
    ,b.IdentifyingNumber AS IdentifyingNumberB
    ,b.Included As IncludedB
INTO #C
FROM #A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #B b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: But TableB have a 7 records and TableA have 5 records so out put is not perfect.

Comment: I've replicated your example precisely, with tables that have three and two records, just as you asked. If it doesn't do what you want, then you didn't ask the question very well.

Comment: I just tried Matt's code in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b244d/3/0) and it shows the expected results of the question.

Comment: @Ninjapig, please you can increase row of TableB and check that out put

Comment: @JeetBhatt At this point - having had someone make the effort to help you exactly as you ask, and you complain about it, ignore them and appeal with a nonsensical request to someone who took the time to confirm that my answer was correct according to the parameters you laid down - I think you're verging on rudeness.

Comment: @JeetBhatt Increasing the record count in table B does not change the results (see [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36be4/1/0)), as expected of a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp). Only increasing the number of records in table A would affect the output, but Matt's answer is still correct for the question that was asked. If you change the number of records your question needs updated to reflect this.